# Unstable MTP mount Android device on Linux

Tags: linux, mount, linux-mint, android, mtp

I have Linux Mint 17.1 (rebecca) MATE edition and a HTC One mini 2. My computer is able to mount the device, and I sometimes get access to both the internal memory and the SD card in the phone.

However, behavior is VERY unstable.
Sometimes, after the device is mounted, it would unmount and later remount again. This would happen in the middle of file transfer sometimes.
Other times, however, the device won't mount at all.

Almost always I also get flooded with error pop-up windows saying:

```
Unable to mount Android Phone
Unable to open MTP device '[usb:002,042]'
```

(the numbers change as more and more erros message windows start appearing).

When I plug in a Samsung tablet I observe similar behevior.
My computer is a Lenovo Ideapad U430p laptop.

Any idea on what could be the reason? I have no clue on how to diagnose the problem or find out what's the package/configuration that is failing.

Comment: I used to get this on 17.2, it was the kernel... Once I updated to a 3.19 or newer kernel, the problem went away.  Could be the cable too.

Comment: Did you find a fix for it? I have Ubuntu 16.04 and a Samsung Galaxy S6, I'm having the same problem. The worst part is that this somehow eats up my battery, and the phone actually loses battery while connected without me even touching it. I just closed 352 of these popups now after 1 hour or so with the phone plugged in. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

If you find this in 2020 and you're getting this error trying to transfer files from a phone which could be mounted in the past, you may have a buggy version of libmtp/gvfs-mtp. A downgrade to 1.1.13 and 1.34.1 can help in that case.

For Fedora 32, there's Bug [1839519](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1839519).